# Creating a Maya UI

Tags: python, maya

I am creating a maya UI but when I try to run my loadobject button command twice after I run my replace_name button once in maya I get this error:

```
cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.loadobject, e=True, text=select_objects[0])
RuntimeError:
```

Hope someone could help me fix this.
Thanks.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


class MyUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "Test UI"
        self.window = cmds.window(self.title, widthHeight=(1000, 600),
                         resizeToFitChildren=1)

        cmds.rowLayout("button1, button2, button3", numberOfColumns=5)

        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True, columnAlign="center",
                      rowSpacing=10)
        self.loadobject = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Load Object name",
                                                  buttonLabel="Load",
                                                  text="Select Object %s."
                                                  % "and Load name",
                                                  buttonCommand=self.load)
        self.basename = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Basename",
                                                buttonLabel="Rename",
                                                text="Enter basename.",
                                                buttonCommand=self.replace_name)
        cmds.setParent(menu=True)

        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def load(self, *args):
        select_objects = cmds.ls(selection=True)
        cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.loadobject, e=True, text=select_objects[0])


    def replace_name(self, *args):
        self.loadobject = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.loadobject,
                                               q=True, text=True)
        self.basename = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.basename,
                                             q=True, text=True)
        name = cmds.rename(self.loadobject, self.basename)
        ctlname = "%s_ctl" % name
        self.new_name = cmds.rename(name, ctlname)
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to do more work on this yourself if you want an answer; Maya is not that well-known and at the moment anyone who wants to help is going to have to grok a lot of code.

Comment: Don't say like 'Maya is not that well-known' !!!

Answer (score 7):

You are using cmds I highly recommend pymel instead
`import pymel.core as pm`
But that is not your issue.

The issue is in the logic.
You have class member vars called `self.loadobject` & `self.basename`. Those 2 represent the name of the Maya UI objects.  When you do a query, you overwrite those vars with the content of the Maya UI objects.

Then when you try to use those 2 objects again Maya is telling you:

> RuntimeError:
>   "Dude who the !@#$ are you talking about?"

I apologize for my friends at Autodesk, they either censored the second line due to the coarse language or just omitted to include a useful debugger in Maya.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

#x=MyUI()
class MyUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "Test UI"
        self.window = cmds.window(self.title, widthHeight=(1000, 600),
                         resizeToFitChildren=1)

        cmds.rowLayout("button1, button2, button3", numberOfColumns=5)

        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True, columnAlign="center",
                      rowSpacing=10)
        self.loadobjectTEXT = "Select Object and Load name"
        self.loadobjectFIELDNAME = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Load Object name",
                                                  buttonLabel="Load",
                                                  text=self.loadobjectTEXT,
                                                  buttonCommand=self.load)
        self.basenameTEXT = "Enter basename."                    
        self.basenameFIELDNAME = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Basename",
                                                buttonLabel="Rename",
                                                text=self.basenameTEXT,
                                                buttonCommand=self.replace_name)
        cmds.setParent(menu=True)

        cmds.showWindow(self.window)


    def load(self):
        select_objects = cmds.ls(selection=True)
        cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.loadobjectFIELDNAME, e=True, text=select_objects[0])


    def replace_name(self, *args):
        self.loadobjectTEXT = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.loadobjectFIELDNAME,
                                               q=True, text=True)
        self.basenameTEXT = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(self.basenameFIELDNAME,
                                             q=True, text=True)
        name = cmds.rename(self.loadobjectTEXT, self.basenameTEXT)
        ctlname = "%s_ctl" % name
        self.new_name = cmds.rename(name, ctlname)
```

Comment: Why recommend pymel over cmds? You never stated any reasons.

Comment: One reason that come to my mind real quick:
Pymel commands returns objects, cmds returns strings. If the name of an object change, your variable is no longer valid. With an object, names don't matter, you indirectly have direct access to the MObject through your PyNode instance.

Object Oriented Programming is better then dealing with constant string manipulations.

Comment: As  side note, this Question was in 2010, I answered it in 2012 to get "slack reputation".
Now, in 2019, I would recommend using a Qt ui instead of building one with Maya commands.
I highly recommend the https://github.com/motosso/Qt.py shim to ensure your uis are compatible between dccs, Maya versions and even your standalone python install.
Do not pre-compile your .ui files. Load them dynamically for the same reasons. 
see https://gist.github.com/liorbenhorin get the MayaDockingClass.py. We have our own version that allow us to load the same .ui in Mobu and python standalone.

Answer (score 1):

plus, I sudgest to use partial for the command

```
from functools import partial

[...]

cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Basename",
                        buttonLabel="Rename",
                        text=self.basenameTEXT,
                        buttonCommand=partial(self.replace_name))
[...]
def load(self, *args):
[...]
```

in this case doesn't really change too mutch to you.
but if you want to pass some varibles partial make your life easer ;)

eg :

```
[...]
cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(label="Basename",
                        buttonLabel="Rename",
                        text=self.basenameTEXT,
                        buttonCommand=partial(self.replace_name, obj))
[...]
def load(self, obj, *args):
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, the issue is with lines 33 and 35 of your code. You are overwriting the textFieldButtonGrp objects with a queried string value of their content. So when you come back and run the query/edit for the second time is when Maya is throwing the error because these two variables no longer hold an instance of a textFieldButtonGrp, they are now a simple string. Just change these two lines from:

```
self.loadobject = ...
self.basename = ...
```

to a localized:

```
loadobject = ...
basename = ...
```

Or, if you need access to them as an instanced variable in other parts of your code, you simply need to use a different variable name as Mathieu explained:

```
self.loadobjectText = ...
self.basenameText = ...
```